# Is Google Cloud Platform's BigTable used only for storing unstructured data or we use it for both structured and unstructured data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

Is Google Cloud Platform's  BigTable used only for storing unstructured data or we use it for both structured and unstructured data?

Comment: this should help: https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/

Comment: Here there is some general information from the official docs about BigTable, how it works or what is it good for: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

Think of Bigtable as a large map of maps.  Each rowkey is an entry in a humungous map pointing to a row.  A row is a map of family + qualifier (+timestamp) -> value.  Bigtable enforces family names, but does not enforce a consistency around qualifiers.

You can store structured data with good engineering practices around having consistent names and types for qualifiers in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can store structured data in Bigtable.  See the original [Whitepaper](https://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) entitled "Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for **Structured** Data"